# Metal piece connecting to oil pan hose loose

Tags: oil, leak, oil-leak, hose, oil-pan

So I noticed oil leakage during high RPM on my car (1999 Saab 9-3) and when I looked underneath I found that the hose connecting to the oil pan was loose and the area around it was damp with oil. Upon closer inspection, I found that the hose itself was not coming off, but the metal piece it connects too (I cant find a name for it anywhere, video showing it [here](https://youtu.be/K7HzBchKIeM))

Can I just hammer this piece back in, do i need to replace it and if so what is it even called? help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have some pictures from further back
[image]

Comment: That is antifreeze; someting to do with the radiator ( can not recognize the photo.)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there anyway to get a broader image of where you're pointing to so we can locate it on the engine? You said "connected to the oil pan", but where? If this is the *type* of connection I think it is at the pan, I'm betting it is meant to be part of the pan and the only way of fixing it is to replace the pan. Not saying to do this quite yet, just get us a better pic and we'll go from there.

Comment: What you're showing in the video does not look like an oil pan or oil pan connection to me.  Perhaps a higher quality photo or two would help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the part you're looking at is the oil return for the turbocharger. I'm not seeing an exact name for it, though. The hose which attaches the two parts is called the oil return hose (part number 9188665 if this is a 2.0L engine ... different for the 2.3L of which I couldn't find the part number). The metal part may be specified as an "oil return elbow" or some such. You might do well to call up a Saab dealership and see if they can provide you the part number for it and possibly order it from there.

If you can find the part, it might tap into place into the block (I'm assuming that's where it is entering at), but getting to seal will require something like Permatex's *The Right Stuff*. (NOTE: I'm not affiliated with Permatex.) The reason I suggest this specific sealant is because it will absolutely seal in a case like this. It's not going to hold the part in place, but it will seal it.

Comment: From here (not affiliated): https://www.saabusaparts.com/Hose-9-3-1998-2011-p/9188665.htm it looks like part number 3 with a new O-ring 5, is what is needed